For loop going past ubound set limit
limit = UBound(arr_1, 1)
For from_idx = 1 To limit
    If from_idx = 2044 Then
        x_break = True 'set watch to action when true
    End If
    For to_idx = 1 To UBound(arr_2, 1)
        If arr-1(from_idx, 1) = arr_2(to_idx, 1) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next to_idx 
Next from_idx 

Issue:
Where Ubound(arr_1,1) = 2044
When I run the code, I get a for loop go past the limit and set from_idx to 2045 when it should not enter that for loop
EDIT:
Both arr_1 and arr_2 sizes
arr_1 (1 to 2044, 1 to 55)
arr_2 (1 to 2366, 1 to 57)

This means that the loop is over

Does that also happen if you specify which counter to increase with "Next"? (e.g. "Next to_idx" and "Next from_idx")

Updated the code above and even when its hard coded to 1 to 2044 doing the same.

@Nicholas Yes even with the Next to_idx and Next from_idx it does the same issue.

Added this and it works If from_idx > UBound(arr_p_available, 1) Then Exit For

What is the purpose of x_break? Please add the code that will do something meaningful inside the loops and/or explain what it should do.

When a For.. To.. is finished, the counter is always +1 if there was no Exit For call. For example: For i = 1 To 10: Next i: Debug.Print i will print 11 in the Immediate window

Also, If from_idx = 2044 Then x_break = True can be rewritten as x_break = (from_idx = 2044). However, if your goal is to 'Break when value is True' in the Watch window then you can just add from_idx = 2044 directly to the watch without needing the extra x_break variable

inside the second for loop, is this code: If arr-1(from_idx,..., with the dash instead of underscore, correct?
